# How to enumerate all reachable objects given a root object?

Tags: c#, reflection, reference

I would like to implement a method that receives a root object and returns a list containing references to all objects that can be reached starting from the root object. Its signature would be something like this:

```
static List<object> EnumerateObjectsInRange(object root);
```

I'm thinking about using [GetProperties()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb.aspx) to retrieve an array of [PropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx) objects, then get these properties' values using [GetValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx) and finally call [GetProperties()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb.aspx) again for each value and repeat this procedure until the entire object graph has been visited, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

I can think of two definitions for *reachable*:

1. All objects the owner of the root object would be able to access (public available objects).
2. All public and private objects referenced by the object graph to which the root object belongs.

The first definition is enough for my purposes.

Comment: You will need a recursive algorithm. Basically it's like a BF search.

Comment: For more/better suggestions you would have to indicate what it's for, and what 'reachable' means exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely need fields, not properties. Objects keep other objects alive via fields, *never* via properties. You don't need to special-case lists because they contain an internal array which you will find using GetFields. You need to special-case arrays, however.

Btw, I have implemented this algorithm and found it to be working and useful.

Comment: Since you have implemented this algorithm yourself, can you tell me if arrays are the only special-case I will find? :)

Comment: Yes they are. You only need to consider "things" which can store references to other objects. Only fields and arrays can do that.

Comment: They can hold anything, it doesn't matter. They will only reference other objects using fields. Their implementation details do not matter. If you need examples, think abount how a linked list or a hashtable look internally. Just fields.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone finds it useful, I'm sharing a recursive method I wrote from **usr** and **Henk's** answers that solved my problem:

```
static void EnumerateObjectsInRange(object root, HashSet<object> hashset)
{
    if (root == null || hashset.Contains(root))
    {
        return;
    }

    hashset.Add(root);
    FieldInfo[] fields = root.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Static
                                                | BindingFlags.Instance
                                                | BindingFlags.Public
                                                | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
    {
        object obj = field.GetValue(root);

        if (obj == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (obj.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Array)))
        {
            foreach (object member in (Array)obj)
            {
                EnumerateObjectsInRange(member, hashset);
            }
        }

        EnumerateObjectsInRange(obj, hashset);
    }
}
```

This method still needs some refactoring (and it is not checking if the HashSet is null), but it gets the job done.

To call it, provide the root object and an empty HashSet where visited objects will be stored.

Comment: Good attempt but still far from ideal. There is a lot of things that needs special handling. For example value-type fields, classes that overrides Equals() and GetHashCode() methods, objects proxied from another AppDomain, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I worked out a solution to handle the case when Equals() and GetHashCode() return the same value for distinct objects using an [ObjectIDGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.objectidgenerator.aspx), and I'm simply ignoring value-type fields because you can't get a reference to them, only copies (but I'm still looking inside them to find out if they hold reference-type fields). Regarding AppDomains, that's way out of my scope.